# É uma má pratica usar as APIs nativas do navegador com React?

Tags: react

Estou utilizando React a pouco tempo, e utilizo bastante as APIs nativas dos navegadores, por exemplo para adicionar ou remover classes com eventos. A minha duvida é, isso é uma má pratica? Eu deveria tentar fazer essas mudanças utilizando Hooks?

Comment: Eu diria ser uma "má prática" sim. Na maioria das vezes, se você está utilizando React, as APIs nativas do navegador tornam-se desnecessárias, uma vez que o React fornece outros meios para que se chegue no "mesmo resultado". Não faz muito sentido misturar.

Comment: Difícil responder algo tão amplo por causa dos *corner cases*. Por exemplo, não é legal usar `document.querySelector`, mas você pode precisar disso para utilizar o [ReactDOM.createPortal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html), que é, então, um caso de uso válido.